# density approximation using monte carlo

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, monte-carlo

I am confused about how i can approximate a probability density function using Monte Carlo simulation.
If we let $X_{1:n}$ be $n$ simulations of a density $p$, then it is said that $$ p(x) \approx \hat{p}(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i}(x)$$
There comes the confusion: what is $\delta_{x_0}(x).$ is it $\mathbb{1}_{x_0}(x)$ or does it put infinite mass on $x_0$ and zeroes everywhere else?
I'm confused about it because i know that if i want to approximate the expectation of $X$, i do the following 
$$ \int xp(x)dx \approx \int x\hat{p}(x)dx = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \int x\delta_{X_i}(x)dx =  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
but then for this to be true, $\delta$ would have to put infinite mass on each $X_i$.
On the other hand, if i want to plot the approximation of $p(x)$, i would use $\mathbb{1}_{X_i}$ but it doesn't seem to be consistent with the Monte Carlo for expectation estimation.

Thank you

Comment: it puts infinite mass on its subscript and zeros everywhere else. In such a way that it always integrates to 1 when the subscript is included in the range.

Comment: the way you've integrated $\int x \delta_{X_i}(x)dx$ is correct

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst then how can i plot an approximation of the pdf using monte carlo? Say i simulate 10000 realizations of the standard gaussian distribution and i want to use those realizations to plot an approximation of the gaussian

Comment: I agree that plotting the dirac delta would be effectively impossible. You could use some kind of numerical approximation to dirac delta which isn't infinite, perhaps using a package in R. Then you can plot this approximation.

Comment: one idea is to approximate $\delta_z(x) = \exp(\frac{-1}{z-|x|^2})$.

Comment: Sounds good! Thank you

Comment: Your Dirac delta puts finite mass at a particular point.  Your problem is that, following the physical analogy, finite mass at a point suggests infinite density.   

You might find it easier to illustrate that this provides an approximation to the cumulative distribution function of the original distribution

Comment: I wrote a blog post about it. I explain what the Dirac-delta function is and how it can be used for sampling, [here](https://maurocamaraescudero.netlify.app/post/towards-smc-using-the-dirac-delta-function-in-sampling-and-sequential-monte-carlo/)

Comment: Really interesting thank you.